# I want to add a new record to the subform, but it always adds a new record to the main form as well

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code to add a new record to the subform but for some reason it always creates a new record in the main form too.

Basically, I want the subform to add details to a certain customer (the customer details are shown in main form) and the subform shows the orders but I have a drop down to select the items and then the values will be used to add a new record to the subform.

The code I used is:

```
With Forms![Student]![Selection subform1]
![Module Code].SetFocus
![Semester 1 Credits].SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
![Module Code] = Sem1select1.Value
![Semester 1 Credits] = Sem1sel1cred.Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the recordsetclone:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

With Me![Selection subform1].Form
    Set rs = .RecordsetClone
    rs.AddNew
        rs![Module Code].Value = Sem1select1.Value
        rs![Semester 1 Credits].Value = Sem1sel1cred.Value
    rs.Update
    ' Move to new record:
    .Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    Set rs = Nothing 
End With
```

Comment: I believe here should be `.Recordset`, not `.RecordsetClone`. RecordsetClone also will work, but the form may not scroll to new record.

Comment: @SergeyS.: Yes, that could be a requirement, so I've added a line setting the _Bookmark_.

Comment: thanks guys appreciate the help. it works like a charm!